# C#, SQL, MVC, Entity Framework, NUnit, Agile phone screen questions

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, nunit

Can anyone suggest any good questions to ask candidates relating to C#, SQL, MVC, Entity Framework, NUnit and Agile?  I will be giving these questions to a recruiter to ask so they can't be too open ended.

Thanks,,

Sachin

Comment: Unless you're looking for EF experience specifically, you can ask about ORM in general.

Comment: Do you have any specific ORM quesitons?

Comment: It's better to have a discussion than to have questions. You can then feel for how much they understand ORM at a high- and low-level, vs. "I'm just using it because our company project uses it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your recruiter doesn't have the skills to actually have a conversation with applicants about these technologies, there's a danger he/she will just be asking trivia questions and letting you know if the applicant got them right. Those types of question might be too specific to be helpful. Any way you can do these interviews yourself?

Example: "ORM Systems address the object-relational impedance mismatch.  What types of problems are caused by this mismatch, and how can ORMs solve them?  How does EF solve them?" - this could lead to an interesting conversation that allows the applicant to showcase both their knowledge and their critical thinking skills, their experience and ability to form an opinion on a technical matter.  If the recruiter asked it you might get back something like "yes, he's heard of the O-R impedance mismatch."

Comment: +1 conversation trumps canned questions (with equally canned answers)